# How to create CGColorSpace from EXIF number?

Tags: ios, objective-c, metadata, core-graphics, cgimagesource

I have a `CGImageSourceRef` with a following metadata:

```
// CGImageSourceCopyMetadataAtIndex
<CGImageMetadata 0x10225ed50> (
    exif:SubsecTimeDigitized = 000
    exif:ColorSpace = 1
    // and more ... 
)


// CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex
{
    ProfileName = "sRGB IEC61966-2.1";
    "{Exif}" =     {
        ColorSpace = 1;
    };
    // and more ...
}
```

"ColorSpace" here is "1". I've seen all constructors of `CGColorSpaceRef`, none of them creates a color space from a number.

`CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(CFStringRef name)` takes a name, which isn't enum, just a bunch of hardcoded strings like `kCGColorSpaceDisplayP3`.

How to create a `CGColorSpace` from this `1` magic number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, currently I'm using `CoreImage` approach because it's simple and fast:

```
CIImage* ciImage = [CIImage imageWithData:rawData];
CGColorSpaceRef cs = ciImage.colorSpace;
```

`CIImage` doesn't have memory overhead if created with pre-allocated bytes.
It also doesn't have performance overhead if not rendered e.g. with `[CIContext render]`.